# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String

Tags: android, string-formatting

I'm trying to format dates which I retrieve from my database table, I wanted to format from "2015 02 11 12 00" to "Feb 2" but it gives an error when I format it. Is there any other ways formatting those dates?

Following the codes:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_events, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All events: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // events found
                // Getting Array of events
                events = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENTS);

                // looping through All events
                for (int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String eventname = c.getString(TAG_EVENTNAME);
                    String eventstart = c.getString(TAG_EVENTSTART);

                  String eventstartconvert = formatdate.format(eventstart); //this line gives an error.


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_EVENTNAME, eventname);
                    map.put(TAG_EVENTSTART,eventstartconvert);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    eventsList.add(map);
                }
            }
```

Here's my logcat:

```
02-11 09:14:40.997  25966-26198/com.example.jithea.testlogin E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String
        at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:359)
        at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
        at com.example.jithea.testlogin.EventsActivity$LoadAllevents.doInBackground(EventsActivity.java:137)
        at com.example.jithea.testlogin.EventsActivity$LoadAllevents.doInBackground(EventsActivity.java:91)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)

Comment: please post the full stack trace for the exception so that we know what line to start looking at.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could you this format for date formating.......

```
DateFormat inputFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = inputFormatter1.parse("2015-2-22");

DateFormat outputFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String output1 = outputFormatter1.format(date1); //
```

// if in this format input is 2015-2-22 than out put will be 22-Feb-2015

Comment: you could set format according to your requirement .... like ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

Answer (score 8):

[`DateFormat.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition)) expects `Number` or `Date` but you are passing it a `String`. You may want to [parse the string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) but formatting it would just produce the same string you would parse.

Comment: `Error:(138, 31) error: no suitable method found for format(SimpleDateFormat,String)` By the way I declared  `SimpleDateFormat formatdate = new SimpleDateFormat("Mmm dd");`

Answer (score 1):

You should format input and then passed to output format

```
try {
    String formattedString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2014-07-31"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```