# Java/Android: how format a date?

Tags: java, android

I like to have a `SupportDate` class in my PHP projects, to use it like a toolbox, so I would it also in my Android projects.

Long story made short:

This is `SupportDate` class:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * Created by Alessandro on 28/06/2015.
 */
public class SupportDate {

    // Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability
    private SupportDate() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public static String getCurrentDate(String format) {
        if (format==null){
            format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        }

        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        final String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());

        return utcTime;
    }

    public static String formatDate(String date, String format){
        if (date==null){
            date = getCurrentDate(null);
        }

        if (format==null){
            format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        }

        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        final String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

        return formattedDate;

    }

}
```

This is my usage, from a value retrieved from database:

```
last_event_placeholder.append(SupportDate.formatDate(last_event,null));
```

The value of `last_event` is a string retrieved from SQLlite : `2015-06-29 10:41:12`

And the error in Log is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String
```

at row `final String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);` of method `formatDate`

Thank you for your help

Comment: whats is your concern? you want to format a date ?

Comment: Yes, I want format a date dinamyc, passing the format as parameter in the method. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you want. I give '20150303' and 'yyyyMMdd' as format, is it return '2015-03-03 00:00:00' in String ?? And you use SimpleDateFormat.format wrong. it should put Date object as argument, not String. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DateFormat.format` expects Number or Date but you are passing it a String. Before passing your date string, you should parse it to a date for example like this:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
Date inputDate = inputFormat.parse(date);
```

and then pass this `inputDate` to your SimpleDateFormat likе this:

```
final String formattedDate = sdf.format(inputDate);
```

Hopefully this helps you :)

P.S. Here you could find more answers [Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445025/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-bad-class-class-java-lang-string)

Answer (score 0):

I use a method of my own where you have to pass input format, input date-timestamp String and expected date format to get the date value in String.
Try this:

```
public static String getDesired(String desiredDateFormat, String inputFormat,String inputStringDate) {

        try {
            Date date = (new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat)).parse(inputStringDate);
            return (new SimpleDateFormat(desiredDateFormat)).format(date);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```